# Detect rectangles in OpenCV (4.2.0) using Python (3.7),

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, contour

I am working on a personal project where I detect rectangles (all the same dimensions) and then place those rectangles inside a list in the same order (top-bottom) and then process the information inside each rectangle using some function. Below is my test image.

[image: Test Image]

I have managed to detect the rectangle of interest, however I keep getting other rectangles that I don't want. As you can see I only want the three rectangles with the information (6,9,3) into a list.

[image: My output when I run my code]

My code

```
import cv2

width=700
height=700
y1=0
y2=700
x1=500
x2=700
img=cv2.imread('test.jpg') #read image
img=cv2.resize(img,(width,height)) #resize image
roi = img[y1:y2, x1:x2] #region of interest i.e where the rectangles will be
gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert roi into gray
Blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),1) #apply blur to roi
Canny=cv2.Canny(Blur,10,50) #apply canny to roi

#Find my contours
contours =cv2.findContours(Canny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]

#Loop through my contours to find rectangles and put them in a list, so i can view them individually later.
cntrRect = []
for i in contours:
        epsilon = 0.05*cv2.arcLength(i,True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i,epsilon,True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            cv2.drawContours(roi,cntrRect,-1,(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.imshow('Roi Rect ONLY',roi)
            cntrRect.append(approx)



cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a feature in Contour called `cv2.contourArea` for which your contour dimensions are input like this `cv2.contourArea(contours)` . You can use the condition,

```
if cv2.contourArea(contours)>#Rectangle area
```

By using this your problem will be solved

Comment: I have used that function, however I get 4 large rectangles instead of 3.

Comment: @AlanJones what is the #Rectangle area you are providing? and are adding it in your `if Statement` with `and` keyword or any other way ?

Comment: I am looping through all the areas to see what the area of each contour is. That is why I see 4 large areas instead of three (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you get the bounding rectangles of the contours and then sort the rectangles by area descending. Crop the first rectangle by default, then loop through the remaining rectangles and crop them if they're, let's say, >=90% of the first rectangle's area. This will ensure that you have the larger rectangles and the smaller ones are ignored.