# How to find a rectangle in an image with python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, shapes

If I have an image with a black background on which various colored rectangles are drawn, how can I find them?
The rectangles are empty but with colored edges (each rectangle has different colors), each rectangle intersects at least one other (the sides of different rectangles do not overlap long but cross and the corners of different rectangles do not overlap), moreover they are aligned with the axis (so they cannot be oblique).
I would like to find how many these rectangles are, which is the smallest of all and what is the order of these rectangles (i.e. see which was drawn first up to which which last) identifying them by color. So I would like to find the length of the edges and the vertices (to see which one is smaller). Without import libraries.

So far I have reasoned like this:

```
for line in range (len (image)):
      for column in range (len (line)):
```

Then I thought about "saving" the colors I encounter in a dictionary, but I don't know how to go on because as the rectangles intersect I'm afraid of working hours on a wrong code.
Can you give me a hand?

This is an example:
https://pasteboard.co/JBHMImK.png

Comment: Can you link an example image?

Comment: Please check the python OpenCV library it should address your needs. Code in this question should give you a headstart in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61166180/detect-rectangles-in-opencv-4-2-0-using-python-3-7

Comment: @RolandDeschain this is the link for the image https://pasteboard.co/JBHMImK.png

Comment: @pholat thanks but i want to use python without import any libraries

Comment: @orsettomorbido is the background always black? Your best (and easiest) shot would still be using opencv. It works with python, so no need for c++

Comment: @RolandDeschain yes, the background is always black. anyway I know that is easiest with opencv, but i'm trying to do it like this to practice while also increasing the difficulty of the problem in question. so I was wondering if there was a way to do it without using libraries

Comment: So are you planning to write a PNG decoder?

Comment: Well to be honest, if you want to do it with additional libs, you already dialed the difficulty up to 100. It's not that easy, and quite an open ended question without opencv or a similar library.